# Please, help with a detailed solution to the limit.

Tags: limits

Good day to all!
I have a problem with this limit:

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \quad\dfrac1{10x^2}+\dfrac1{\cos6x+\cosh4x-2}$$

[Problem and answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDDyW.png)

Please, can you describe in detail how to solve this limit.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Express $cos(6x)$ in terms of $cos(x)$ and $cosh(4x)$ in $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$

Comment: Could you send me a pic of full solution, please?

Comment: Just combine the fractions as one and use L'Hopital twice.

Comment: @elliot Are you familiar with Taylor expansions?

Comment: It is expected that you will give Readers some more precise context that just the problem statement, "I have a problem with this limit."  Your above Comment "Could you send me a pic of full solution, please?" is not in keeping with the mission of Math.SE to collect and curate content helpful to learners of mathematics at all levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution using [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(\dfrac1{10x^2}+\dfrac1{\cos6x+\cosh4x-2}\right)&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac1{10x^2}+\frac1{(1-\frac{(6x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(6x)^4}{4!}+O(x^6))+(1+\frac{(4x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(4x)^4}{4!}+O(x^6))-2} \right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac1{10x^2}+\frac1{-10x^2+\frac{194}3x^4+O(x^6)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{-\frac{194}3x^4+O(x^6)}{10x^2(10x^2+\frac{194}3x^4+O(x^6))}\right)\\
&=\frac{-194}{3}/100\\
&=-\frac{97}{150}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks a lot for easy solution!

Comment: You're welcome!